# Cant access to PHP page in sub directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, directadmin

I have a Wordpress on main domain peiloo.com .

I create a subdomain and install a script on subdomain, but I can't access to any PHP page of sub directory.

For example, when I go to shopping.peiloo.com, I can see that and any page of this folder, but when I want to see http://shopping.peiloo.com/admin/login.php or any page of another folder I see a white page but in my local host I can see all pages.

Comment: Echo in Login page At the top. Maybe some PHP Error. Enable `error_reporting(E_ALL)`

Comment: I enable error_reporting(E_ALL) but anything dosent happend.

Comment: Echo in Login page At the top.

Comment: you need to check your error log.

Comment: this is error log error: [Tue Jun 16 00:45:16.730545 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 284800] AH01909: www.peiloo.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think  there is an issues with the .htaccess file. Can you please try to rename that and check this again.